# Ffmpeg Error on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, paperclip, video-processing

hello i have a ffmpeg on server vps but when i convert a only a video from webcam i have a error

```
Comand
Command 'PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; ffmpeg -i '/tmp/4158602f121d1e6f0dc8ba45a4c25fa620150630-21866-dylnjx.webm' -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -acodec aac -strict experimental -y '/tmp/4158602f121d1e6f0dc8ba45a4c25fa620150630-21866-dylnjx20150630-21866-i25cmw.mp4''

App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] AVFrame.format is not set
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] AVFrame.width or height is not set
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] Input picture width (1280) is greater than stride (0)
App 21834 stderr: Video encoding failed
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: frame I:125   Avg QP:16.63  size: 53542
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: frame P:8143  Avg QP:18.97  size:  1151
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: frame B:22849 Avg QP:27.42  size:    52
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: consecutive B-frames:  2.0%  0.1%  0.2% 97.6%
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: mb I  I16..4: 19.2% 71.8%  9.1%
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  0.4%  0.0%  P16..4:  5.1%  0.8%  0.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:92.7%
App 21834 stderr: [libx264 @ 0x374e440] 
App 21834 stderr: mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.6%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.4%  L0:17.2% L1:82.8% BI: 0.0%


App 21834 stderr: [aac @ 0x383e9c0] 
App 21834 stderr: 2 frames left in the queue on closing
App 21834 stderr: Conversion failed!
App 21834 stderr: ffmpeg version git-2015-04-15-c5d4f87 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
App 21834 stderr:   built with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
App 21834 stderr:   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
App 21834 stderr:   libavutil      54. 22.101 / 54. 22.101
```

App 21834 stderr:   libavcodec     56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
App 21834 stderr:   libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
App 21834 stderr:   libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
App 21834 stderr:   libavfilter     5. 14.100 /  5. 14.100
App 21834 stderr:   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
App 21834 stderr:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
App 21834 stderr:   libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
App 21834 stderr: Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/tmp/4158602f121d1e6f0dc8ba45a4c25fa620150630-21866-dylnjx.webm':

```
App 21834 stderr: video:59kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

App 21866 stdout: Validation failed: Video presentacion error while processing video for 4158602f121d1e6f0dc8ba45a4c25fa620150630-21866-dylnjx: Command 'PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; ffmpeg -i '/tmp/4158602f121d1e6f0dc8ba45a4c25fa620150630-21866-dylnjx.webm' -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -acodec aac -strict experimental -y '/tmp/4158602f121d1e6f0dc8ba45a4c25fa620150630-21866-dylnjx20150630-21866-i25cmw.mp4'' returned 1. Expected 0
```

Comment: can't really tell. What format is on the input? try adding `ffprobe -show_streams -print_format json -v quiet << INPUT FILE >>` to the question as it's not really clear what's going on on the input side

Comment: thanks i using a paperclipt gem for ruby on rails and paperclip-ffmpeg i don't show a command on development mode run but is for ffmpeg? only on server don't work :/

Comment: missing ffmpeg plugin installed?